# Hyper -V 2012-R2 Expanding VHDX for VM did not expand the current file size

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

Hyper-V 2012-R2 with 1 VM (Windows 7). I increased the VM disk size from 60 GB to 80 GB and the operation completed OK. When I click on "Inspect Disk", it says:
  Current File Size: 59.97 GB  Maximum disk Size: 82 GB

When I go on the VM ->drive C: -> Properties: Capacity 59.8 GB

Why it didn't increase the current file size capacity to 82 GB ?

Notes: The server has only one physical HDD and the VHDX is IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increasing the vhdx doesn't increase the volume size  inside the vm. So when you look at the c: drive size in the vm it will not change.

You need to open disk management and expand the volume to be the size of the vhdx. This won't instantly increase the file size on the host but it will show the extra available free space.

This link explains how to expand the volume in Windows 7 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx#BKMK_CMD

Comment: Well dang it. I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score -2):

A VHDX is a dynamically expanding virtual hard disk. The file size will expand as the virtual guest consumes more of the VHDX.

Comment: My bad. I didn't read the question carefully enough. You're talking about the volume size within the guest, not the VHDX file size, correct?